# Handling null when getting data from database

Tags: javascript

Where is the best place to throw an exception when you don't get the item you're looking for?

When I do that in service layer,

```
async function placeOrder(userId: number, productId: number): void {

  const user = await userRepository.findById(userId)
  if(!user) throw new NotFoundError('user not found')

  const product = await productRepository.findById(productId)
  if(!product) throw new NotFoundError('product not found')

  ...
  ...
}
```

I have multiple if statements which isn't good for readability, and it gets worse if I need to get many different resources. Though it's explicit when I get an exception.

I was wondering if it's good practice that a repository throws an error, like

```
async findById(userId: number, options?: {required?: boolean}): User {

  const user = await User.findById(userId)
  if(options && options.required && !user) throw new NotFoundError('user not found')
  return user

}
```

Should my code be clear about when I get an exception in service layers, or should I reduce the amount of `if(!item)`?

Comment: I wouldn't thrown an exception in something like `findById` if you don't find the user because it's not THAT big of an error. In many cases this might be fine and you might even use it to check something different, so no record found is not something you have to sound the alarms for. In something like `placeOrder`, this *might* be an error condition. A non-existent user should probably not be placing an order, for example. Although this might still be an OK thing and you can just return the success status in some form. Exceptions should be...well, exceptional circumstances.

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you for your comment. Yes that makes sense. Often `findById` returning null is not an 'exceptional' case indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Questions like these are very hard to answer, but in my experience, exceptions should always be managed on the service layer. You want all the business logic in one place. With that said, I found VLAZ comment quite on point when it comes to cases where a record can't be found. Not finding a record or a list of records given some parameters should be managed on the *controller* or directly on your *views*.

Now, although it can be quite verbose, I would always recommend the use of exceptions. Is better to handle errors using exceptions. So having many checks, in this case *if*, doesn't necessary mean less readability, but it will help to maintain the application, since the user will have a more explained output of what went wrong in a given operation.

So, go ahead and use as many *exceptions* as you want, but only use them for errors and not for common situations like a no records found on a given query, just like VLAZ mentioned.

Comment: Thank for your comment. I normally throw exceptions in service layer, but in the project I'm working on currently I need 4-5 resources to perform a specific task. Then many 'if then throw' blocks are a bit hard to read and I was not sure that was a good practice. But I agree with that users will have more information by that. I will stick to it.

Answer (score 0):

I do exactlly like u. I think that's the best way to control which errors you wanna display in the front-end.